# Rails update_all in one query with index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here's my function in my controller:

```
def sort
  params[:state].each_with_index do |id, index|
    State.update_all({:position => index+1, :country_id => params[:country_id]}, {:id => id})
  end
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Here's my output:

```
Started POST "/countries/83/states/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Apr 19 00:02:56 +0800 2012
  Processing by StatesController#sort as JS
  Parameters: {"country_id"=>"83", "state"=>["378", "381", "380"]}

ApplicationController::current_user_session
  Country Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = 83 LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE `states` SET `country_id` = '83', `position` = 1 WHERE `states`.`id` = 378
  SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE `states` SET `country_id` = '83', `position` = 2 WHERE `states`.`id` = 381
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE `states` SET `country_id` = '83', `position` = 3 WHERE `states`.`id` = 380
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE `countries` SET `updated_at` = '2012-04-19 00:02:56' WHERE `countries`.`id` = 83
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 559ms (Views: 13.0ms | ActiveRecord: 39.3ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

Obviously the above doesn't run in one query, because I couldn't get the index to step up.

What I want to do is to run this in one query with `index`. The `position` should always start with `1` based on the arrangement of the id array `[378, 381, 380]`.

In brief: the result above is correct, but I want to run it in one query.

NOTE: It must be generic SQL, which must work in both MySQL and Postgres. Because I think the `FIND_IN_SET` works in MySQL, but not Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to sort a list of model objects based on the `:position` attribute?

If so i would suggest a linked list approach might be better. It can be done really easily with the [Resort gem](https://github.com/codegram/resort). It contains some pretty useful helper methods too:

```
Product.first_in_order # returns the first ordered product.
Product.last_in_order # returns the last ordered product.
Product.ordered # returns all products ordered as an Array, not a Relation!
```

That's unless i've misunderstood what you're trying to do…

Comment: Yes, you have. :P I am trying to apply the `.sortable()` function from jQuery to add the positions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how much it will help but i got this plugin working using the following code, the model im sorting is Step

Gemfile

```
# Use jquery-ui
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.5'
```

Require in application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

View: (I used a table but a ul works too
In the table body add:

```
<tbody id="steps" data-update-url="<%= sort_course_steps_url %>">
```

For each table row add:

```
<tr id="step_<%= step.id %>">
```

Javascript: Apply sortable and post serialized data

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $('#steps').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function() {
     return $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
    }
  });
});
```

Routes

```
resources :steps do
    collection {post :sort}
end
```

Controller:

```
def sort
  params[:step].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Step.where(id:id).update_all(order: index+1)
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```

Comment: This doesn't help, he's asking how to run the sort function in one query, as it stands it's an n+1 query.